# Piper won't stop being naked

Tags: fallout-4

Piper is my companion, and I got her to stay in the Starlight Drive-in. I did the interview for her, went and did some quests, came back and she is running around in my power armour (should have taken the fusion core!)

After a few minutes, she leaves the power armour in her underwear and runs off to start farming.

I've traded with her and given her a variety of clothing: vault suits, long johns, combat armour, but she never wears any of it.

My family are beginning to think I'm playing some kind of weird game involving big green mutants and small naked girls - how can I get Piper to wear some clothes?

Comment: And why exactly is this an issue? ;-) Maybe she has the "nudist" trait? :)

Comment: Are you just trading things with her, or are you actually equipping the stuff for her?

Comment: Trading with her, how can I equip it for her @Polygnome?

Comment: You *are* playing a game involving big green mutants and small naked girls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible that when she got in the power armor she had to take part of her outfit off. I believe sometimes people do this when entering power armor for some reason (possibly to make room to "fit" into the armor despite the fact that *you* can enter power armor without taking clothing off).

To equip an item on a companion:

1. Place the item in their inventory
2. Hover over it/select it, then press the equip button (`Y` for Xbox, triangle for PS4, and <kbd>T</kbd> for PC).

Note that you can do this for settlers as well.